# Magento 2 - Change the entire width of theme

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, theme, luma-theme

I want to adjust the entire width of the Luma or Blank theme (I prefer Blank theme).

What is the best way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best way to increase width of the entire theme is by overriding value of `@layout__max-width` variable. Look into *lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_layout.less* file which controls

```
//  Widths
@layout__width: ''; // for the fixed width layout
@layout__max-width: 1280px;
@layout-indent__width: 20px;
@layout__width-xs-indent: 15px;
```

you can override value e.g. `@layout__max-width: 1400px;` in theme override file e.g.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/source/_theme.less

Comment: One of the easiest core definitions to miss. Great tip.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is create your own theme that inherits the luma theme.

You can create a theme like this (no point in copy/pasting that whole page , just follow it step by step):

[Create own theme in Magento 2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11754)

Keep in mind that in your theme.xml you don't want to have the parent set to blank but to luma like this :

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>New theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
     <parent>Magento/luma</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
     <media>
         <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
     </media>
 </theme>
```

After you done so go to **Content->Design->Configuration** and choose your theme within the website/storefront that you want to implement it.

After you have done that you can make changes to the css of your theme.

Create a `web/css/source` folder. Within this folder you can create your own .less files that it will compile to css when you delete your `/var` folder and `/pub/static` folder and regenerate your static files.

Its a good practice to create a `_extend.less` when you want to make **new** css stylings that you added to your **.pthml** files

If you just want to **edit** the existing css of Magento you can just overwrite them in a `_theme.less` file.

These will be compiled within the styles-l.css and styles-m.css so your storefront still loads that 1 file (and thus reduces load time of your website because you didn't add files to load in).

In you case you want to create a **'_theme.less'** file within your created source directory and add the following code :

```
 #maincontent{
max-width : 100%;
}
```

You can create paddings (i suggest you create paddings for it) in that how you want to overwrite the settings of `.page-main` class.

Also i recommend people to use **Bootstrap 4** and implement that in their sites to have some content management but that another topic.

**I hope this is enough information for you**

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer but  #maincontent will adjust the width of main column, I need the entire theme width this include header, footer ...

Comment: Then you need to use the class page-wrapper

Comment: but thats already 100% width. If you want to delete the paddings on the nav menu and max-width you need to go over every class and overwrite the stylings like i said. There is no 1 thing for that. A good start is to have the class "content" its style set to width 100% and max-width 100%

Comment: If you feel like this helped you out don't forget to check it as an answer and give it a thumbs up ;)

Comment: of course, for sure

Comment: no problem , thats what the exchange is for