# Change width in custom theme - Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, theme-fallback

I created a new theme inheriting from Luma based on some totorias, the only change I made was to put it in _theme.less

```
// Widths
@layout__width: '';
@ layout__max-width: 100%;
@ layout-indent__width: 10px;
@ layout__width-xs-indent: 10px;
```

Actually the screen was 100%, but the header, menu and footer lost the original format and font of Luma. Shouldn't I inherit from the luma theme? Did I miss something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution.

Best way to increase width of the entire theme is by overriding value of `@layout__max-width` variable. Look into **lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_layout.less** file which controls

```
//  Widths
@layout__width: ''; // for the fixed width layout
@layout__max-width: 1280px;
@layout-indent__width: 20px;
@layout__width-xs-indent: 15px;
```

you can override value e.g. `@layout__max-width: 1400px;` in theme override file e.g.

> **`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/source/_theme.less`**

And you want to check more information check this link :-

**[Magento 2 - Change the entire width of theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199085/magento-2-change-the-entire-width-of-theme)**

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: It was exactly what I did, but the rest was unconfigured, as you can see in the image on the home page

Comment: you change after run all commands